# Renaming columns in a QGIS attribute table with Python

Tags: pyqgis

I have some vector shape files with many columns.
I need to change the name of each column in the header from the old name to a more generic "Img1", "Img2", "Img3", etc progressively, starting from column #5 and leaving the name of columns 1 to 4 unchanged.

I wrote this Python code to be used with QGIS but it doesn't work.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
nImg = 1
nCol = len(layer.pendingFields())
cont = (5,nCol)
for field in cont:
    with edit (layer):
        oldName = layer.fieldNameIndex(field.name())
        newName = "Img" + str(nImg)
        layer.renameAttribute(oldName, newName)
    nImg = + 1
```

The error is

```
oldName = layer.fieldNameIndex(field.name())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I tried also changing

```
with edit (layer)
```

to

```
layer.startEditing()
```

and unindenting the rows, but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify whether you are trying to change the field presentation associated with the *layer* or the actual column names in the *source table*.

Comment: Hi Vince, I edited the text and I specified that I'm talking about shapefiles and I need to rename the header of the attribute tables. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown by this line:

```
oldName = layer.fieldNameIndex(field.name())
```

and it is saying that `field` is an integer not an object with a `name` method. Also checking the [documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a45a4cafbd2a9bad1faac112821f77b61) shows that:

> int QgsFeature::fieldNameIndex (   const QString &     fieldName   )
>   const Utility method to get attribute index from name.
>
> Field map must be associated using setFields() before this method can
>   be used.
>
> Parameters fieldName  name of field to get attribute index of Returns
>   -1 if field does not exist or field map is not associated.

So it looks up the index of a field based on its name, but you want to find the name based on its index. To do this you need to grab the [`qgsFields` map](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFields.html) using the [`fields` method](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a104bcd72de229217da70f3f90f1c1c44). So something like:

```
fields = layer.fields()
for field in cont:
with edit (layer):
    oldName = fields.at(field).name()
    newName = "Img" + str(nImg)
    layer.renameAttribute(oldName, newName)
nImg = + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your GIS data format is **shapefile** then you can change the field names using the **DBF python library** as the attributes are defined in the DBF file:

```
import dbf
layer = dbf.Table('dbf_file')
cont = layer.field_names
try:
    for oldName in cont:
        newName = "Img" + str(nImg)
        layer.rename_field(oldName, newName)
        nImg = + 1
finally:
    layer.close()
```

Comment: What if the dataset isn't shapefile?

Comment: @Vince you are right, I missed that :(

Comment: dbf library seems good, but I couldn't make it working. I get this error message     "raise DbfError('%s not in read/write mode, unable to change field names' % meta.filename)"

Comment: @ilFonta you will need to use `layer.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)` after reading the file .. se here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314270/cant-write-dbf-file

Comment: I notice that dbf can only handle alphanumeric characters and _ in field names. Shape file however allows for other characters, such as ()

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that works for my issue

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
nImg = 1
startCol = 5
endCol = len(layer.pendingFields())
countCol = (range(startCol,endCol,1))
for colNumber in countCol:
    with edit (layer):
        newName = "Img" + str(nImg)
        layer.renameAttribute(colNumber, newName)
        nImg = nImg + 1
```